# MySQL Syntax error near '' myguests '' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the MySQL database backup using the php. But currently facing the given error. Anybody can tell me that how can I get rid from this error.

```
<?php
    $db_server="server";
    $db_username="username";
    $db_password="";
    $db_database="database";
    $db_tablename="myguests";

    $db_connection = mysqli_connect("$db_server","$db_username","$db_password","$db_database");
    if(!$db_connection){
        die("Database connection error: ".mysqli_errorno());
    }  

    $db_backup= "/db_backup/";

    $db_select = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$db_backup' FROM '$db_tablename'";

    $retval = mysqli_query($db_connection,$db_select);
    if(!$retval){
        die(/*"Could not take data backup: "*/mysqli_error($db_connection));
    }else{
        echo "Database backup successfully done";
    }
    mysqli_close($db_connection);   
?>
```

Comment: This has countless dupes. Remove the single quotes around table names

Comment: Now Facing "The file '/db_backup' already exists" error. but when I check there is no such a folder exits

Answer (score 0):

You have put your database name in single quotes.

It should be back ticks.

Change:

```
$db_select = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$db_backup' FROM '$db_tablename'";
```

To:

```
$db_select = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$db_backup' FROM `$db_tablename`";
```

Also, no need to put double quotes here, it will work without them also:

```
$db_connection = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
```